# Get extract of Sybase data as INSERT statements, with order considering table dependencies

Tags: sybase, sybase-ase

I want to create a SQL script to populate a DEV database using INSERT statements. (Preferably using INSERT statements, rather than binary form, so that I can safely check-in the script to version control).

I can easily extract the INSERT statements using various tools.  But I haven't found a way to extract the INSERT statements *in an order so that when run, FK constraints will not be violated.*

I've used SQL Server tools which accomplish this.  e.g. RedGate.  But cannot seem to find a Sybase compatible method.  I'd like a way to write the code to extract the T-SQL statements in the correct order to properly support relational integrity.

Comment: The easiest way is to enable/create the FKs _after_ populating the data, something like: 1. create the table, 2. insert the data, 3. create the indexes, 4. create the foreign keys

Comment: Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name, I did consider that. However we keep our schema structure checked in separately (which includes FK definitions), so I didn't want duplicate definitions existing.